# How to "destroy" a CoreData instance of an object?

Tags: swift, core-data

I use CoreData in my App. Therefor I have a question how to destroy an instance which I generated via:

```
MyObject(context: moc)
```

Usually I do some checking and then save a new object

```
if moc.hasChanges {
    try? moc.save()
}
```

But I don't want to save it, I want to remove it again. If I just do nothing, the objects exists till I restart the app.

Comment: [`delete(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506847-delete) the object then [`save()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506866-save) the changes, I reckon.

Comment: this is working fine, post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a management-object-context you save usually the performed *changes*.

So, deleting an object is one of the possible *changes* you can perform in this context, so it would be just following this logic:

1. just [`delete(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506847-delete) the object;
2. then [`save()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506866-save) these changes;

---

***NOTE:** If you want to read more about Core Data and the Management Object Context, [Apple's API docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext) are actually good read about the topic.*